# npm start issues for angularjs project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm

working on a website, when I started having having issues running npm start for it.  It's an angular project. Can anyone help me?  It was working fine yesterday, I've tried everything from online, error below:

```
> $ npm start
>     
>     > angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart C:\dev\HyprPortal
>     > npm install
>     
>     npm WARN package.json Dependency 'karma' exists in both dependencies and devDependencies, using 'karma@^1.0.0' from
> dependencies
>     
>     > angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall C:\dev\HyprPortal
>     > bower install
>     
>     
>     > angular-seed@0.0.0 start C:\dev\HyprPortal
>     > http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app
>     
>     events.js:141
>           throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>           ^
>     
>     Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000
>         at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
>         at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
>         at Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)
>         at listen (net.js:1270:10)
>         at net.js:1379:9
>         at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:64:16)
>         at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:83:10)
>     
>     npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
>     npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
>     npm ERR! node v4.4.5
>     npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
>     npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>     npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 start: `http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app`
>     npm ERR! Exit status 1
>     npm ERR!
>     npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 start script 'http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app'.
>     npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
>     npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>     npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>     npm ERR!     http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app
>     npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>     npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-seed
>     npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>     npm ERR!
>     npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
>     npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>     
>     npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>     npm ERR!     C:\dev\HyprPortal\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000` Tells me that you are already running something at port 8000. Are you running 2 versions of the same app?

Comment: address already in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is `EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000`. Or in other words - `ERROR: ADDRESS IN USE 127.0.0.1:8000`. Meaning, something is already listening on port 8000.

Make sure you aren't trying to run `npm start` multiple times. Or you can use `netstat -ab` in an Administrative Command Prompt, to see what is listening on that port and kill the process or change the port of your node server.